# My domain PageRank shows as unavailable, why is that?

Tags: domains, pagerank, blog

My domain, http://www.anovaordemmundial.com , has been snatched by some opportunist when I failed to renew the domain. I know, it's all my fault :/ . After I have being ripped off and bought my domain back, and everything is configured and working, the pagerank for that domain shows as unavailable.

Also searches for "nova ordem mundial" (in portuguese), which used to show my domain as the first result in searches in any language, now don't show it anymore.

Do you think this is something temporary and it will recover its pagerank after a full crawl by google? There exists hundreds of sites pointing to my domain, that is why I got the previous relevance in searches.

The domain is back for more than 5 days already. In reality, bing already

Is there anything I can do to help get my domain back to its pagerank???

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Five days? Nothing happens with PR in five days. You probably have to wait for weeks or months before you can see a PR update in your toolbar However, that doesn't mean you don't have any PR yet. You just can't see it yet.

Do you use Google webmaster tools? If so check to see if there are any messages for you from Google. The temporary owners may have done some things that warrant action by you to correct it.

Comment: he following is what I have in my robots.txt, according to the google webmaster tool:
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google
Disallow: 
User-agent: *
Disallow: /search
Sitemap: http://www.anovaordemmundial.com/feeds/posts/default?orderby=updated

There is also a few errors for 1st sept, when I lost the domain. On the Crawl stats seems that the pages started to be crawled again, although not in the same level as pre-sept/1st

As a sidenote, I found in that tool that my blog has 243,025 links to it.

Comment: Google updates visible Toolbar PageRank 3-4x a year, so I'd certainly give it more time -- not to mention that Toolbar PageRank is not something that is worth worrying about anyway :-).

Comment: What worries me is that my site used to show up in the first place when doing certain searches. Now, it doesn't show at all, unless it is very specific.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a lot of instances where domain's changing hands can cause indexing issues (IE if they just parked your domain or put up a place holder all of the URL's that were indexed would return as 404 this will cause them to drop out of the index given enough time, or auto increment settings cause all of the page/post ID's to change in the URL string making new URLs for your entire site when you restore from a backup, etc.) I would do a quick check to see how the number of indexed pages now correlates to the number of pages indexed before. It may be as simple as running some redirects and building new links to key pages.

Comment: The blog was re-instated  in the exactly same way it was before. It just lost the known DNS and after getting it back all links work as before.

Comment: Still, almost 2 months it has been back in place, with all links as it was before, and it hasn't even recovered 10% of what it was before :(

Answer (score 0):

PageRank

Google Pagerank is one way to judge website visibility and authenticity. Google Pagerank is still considered as important factor while evaluating any website. This is particularly helpful when you are planning to buy sell any website or text links.o